# Traverse and filter xml nodes in VBScript

Tags: xml, vbscript

how can I get company, firstname, lastname, mobile, email, country, city and zipcode  values for each customer from the below xml? I tried the following code but when some value is missing (e.g. email in the first record) the code assigns value from the next record so "ABCars" gets "gwood@gmail.com".

Also, do you know how can I filter the loaded records so that only records with mobile number not existing in another recordset left (recordset is not included in the below code)?

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.async="false"
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xmlDoc.load("test.xml")

set  nodes=xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//customer")
for i=0 to nodes.length-1
set company=xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//customer/company")
set firstname=xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//customer/firstname")
set lastname=xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//customer/lastname")
set mobile=xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//customer/mobile")
set email=xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//customer/email")
set country=xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//customer/address/country")
set city=xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//customer/address/city")
set zipcode=xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//customer/address/zipcode")
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
    <category>Cars</category>
    <customers>
        <customer>
            <company>ABCars</company>
            <firstname>Peter</firstname>
            <lastname>Heinrich</lastname>
            <mobile>9141453027</mobile>
            <address>
                <country>Germany</country>
                <city>Berlin</city>
                <zipcode>12345</zipcode>
            </address>
        </customer>
        <customer>
            <company>Best Cars</company>
            <firstname>George</firstname>
            <lastname>Wood</lastname>
            <mobile>123456789</mobile>
            <email>gwood@gmail.com</email>
            <address>
                <country>Great Britain</country>
                <city>Leicaster</city>
                <zipcode>67890</zipcode>
            </address>
        </customer>
    </customers>
</list>
```

Regards,
Przemek

Answer (score 3):

Your loop goes through `nodes` collection but the loop body queries the whole document for each iteration, so you are doing the same query every time - use the returned nodes as context nodes to select nodes relative to that node:

```vb
set  nodes=xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//customer")
for i=0 to nodes.length-1
    ' get the current node
    set node = nodes(i)
    ' run xpath relative to the current node
    set company = node.selectSingleNode("company")
    set firstname = node.selectSingleNode("firstname")
    set lastname = node.selectSingleNode("lastname")
    set mobile = node.selectSingleNode("mobile")
    set email = node.selectSingleNode("email")
    set country = node.selectSingleNode("address/country")
    set city = node.selectSingleNode("address/city")
    set zipcode = node.selectSingleNode("address/zipcode")

next
```

If there is no node found by the XPath query, `Nothing` will be returned which you can check and route appropriately:

```vb
set company = node.selectSingleNode("company")
if company is Nothing then
    ' do something if no company, eg break loop
    exit for
end if
```

For the filtering, you could build your XPath query to select only those nodes which aren't in that list, eg

```vb
dim xpath: xpath = Empty

do until recordset.EOF
    if xpath <> "" then
       xpath = xpath & " and "
    end if 
    xpath = xpath & "mobile != '" & recordset("mobile") & "'"

    recordset.MoveNext
loop

if xpath <> "" then
    xpath = "[" & xpath & "]"
end if

' eg you end up with something like "//customer[mobile != 123456789 and mobile != 987654321]" 
set nodes = xmldoc.selectNodes("//customer" & xpath)
```

Comment: Perfect, many thanks! I was just wondering if there's any easier way to filter the records e.g. using filter() - http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_filter.asp? Could it be used with a recordset?

Comment: @PrzemyslawWojda the ADODB recordset has its own `Filter` functionality:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/1510860/3898606